# How to Replace a separate mesh

Tags: linked-data

I have made a tree with the sapling Addon. I want my leaves to be replace with the icosphere. I want to make the grapes bunch. Is there any way to replace the leaves to icosphere.

[image]

[image]

I tried with object Data but i have to select manually single leaves and object data. I want to replace all the leaves to icosphere. Any suggestion or help. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**This answer is about selecting the leaves.**

Select and hide  <kbd>H</kbd>  the icosphere and the wood (tree without the leaves).

Now select all the leaves  <kbd>A</kbd>  and give them a material.

In **Relations Tab** click in **Object Data >> Link Data**.

Now you can select all the leaves by its material.

See the image below.

[image]

Comment: I think you did not get what i mean. I want to replace all the leaves with the icosphere. Where the leaves i need icosphere

Comment: You made two questions. This answer is about selecting all the leaves.

Comment: No the question is same from before. In short replace the leaves with icosphere.

Comment: Copied from your question: "but i have to select manually single leaves and object data".